# Android Firebase cannot resolve method getRef(position)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I see there are a lot of examples in github where people are using such method:

```
String postKey = getRef(position).getKey();
```

But in my Android Studio it does not resolve `getRef(int)` method. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    articleModel = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        articleModel.add(postSnapshot.getValue(ArticleModel.class));
    }

    adapter = new ArticleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.fragment_article_list_items, articleModel);

    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleDetailsActivity.class);
            String postKey = getRef(position).getKey();
            intent.putExtra(ArticleDetailsActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postKey);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve this problem?

Comment: can you give the link where you see `getRef(position)` working?

Comment: https://github.com/ikotrabakov/FireBlog/blob/017d8fe4df7b61ece00cad3e828e4a7cc8c5adcc/app/src/main/java/com/ivaylok/fireblog/MainActivity.java

Comment: Most likely you're looking for adapter.getRef(position).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function as `getRef` actually in Firebase API.

So far I've understood that you're trying to put an `onItemClickListener` to your `ListView` and you're trying to pass some `key` to the `ArticleDetailsActivity`. So I think, as you've populated the `articleModel` list you can find the key in there.

So the modified code might look like this.

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleDetailsActivity.class);

        // Find the key in the list you've populated earlier. 
        String postKey = articleModel.get(position).getKey();

        intent.putExtra(ArticleDetailsActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postKey);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```