# Android Firebase cannot resolve method getRef(position) from listview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner to android studio! I am trying to retrieve the key(also known as the barcode for my app) from google firebase when I click on the respective listview. I would like to retrieve the respective keys and is facing a cannot resolve method error. eg. I click on the 1st ListView with the pname:"dick", i would like to retrieve only the key(barcode), 97, so that i can pass the key to another java activity so that i can retrieve the rest of the data in another activity. Hope i didnt get the logic wrong

Here is a pic of my database:

[image]

I have tried many different code such as :[Android Firebase cannot resolve method getRef(position)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971476/android-firebase-cannot-resolve-method-getrefposition).
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

```
private Button AddProduct;
private DatabaseReference database;
private ListView mList;
private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory);
    AddProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddProduct);


    AddProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Inventory.this, AddProduct.class));
        }
    });

    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    mList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           String value = (String) mList.getItemAtPosition(i);
            //Toast.makeText(Inventory.this,value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Inventory.this,Edit.class);
            intent.putExtra("fk",value);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            arrayAdapter.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                String barcode = (String) snapshot.child("barcode").getValue();
                String name = (String) snapshot.child("pname").getValue();
                String exp = (String) snapshot.child("expiration").getValue();
                String q = (String) snapshot.child("quantity").getValue();
                arrayAdapter.add("Product Name: "+name+"\nExpiry Date: "+exp+ "\nQuantity: "+q+"\nBarcode: "+ barcode);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            int index = keys.indexOf(key);

            names.set(index, value);

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Update: I tried using either one of the code as shown below, but both shows cannot resolve method error! Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below are the codes i have tried out, but to no avail
[image]

Comment: What is the error when you are using `getRef(position)`? If there is no error, what does the that line print?

Comment: @AlexMamo the getRef(position) show a cannot resolve method! I have tried another code as you can see from my Update, both of the codes have cannot resolve method error! Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you need to use the following line of code:

```
String value = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

To use the value in another activity you can use an `Intent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("value", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks alot Alex, I applied your code to a Toast, and it displays the respective data that i have clicked. But i need the get the key, for example : I click on the 1st ListView with the pname:"dick", i would like to retrieve only the key(barcode), 97, so that i can pass the key to another java activity so that i can retrieve the rest of the data in another activity.

Comment: Is there everything ok? If you think that my answer helped you for the initial and second question, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the key from Firebase Database, you ought to replace this code

```
    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
```

and replace it with the following:

```
    Object key= dataSnapshot.getKey();
    String myKey = key.toString()
```

In android you need to specify an object, that will pick the key from firebase which you will have to convert using toString() method, for it to be used in android!

Comment: How am i suppose to get the position from listview?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because `this` references `OnItemClickListener` and not your `DatabaseReference`.

`database.getRef().getKey()` instead of `this.getRef().getKey()` should work.

Also, you might need to take a look at the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#getRef()) as `getRef()` does not take any argument.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply but unfortunately still have errors. Error:(63, 40) error: method getRef in class Query cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length